# Fakechroot with python

Tags: python, chroot

I have some python code that I want to run in a chroot. The code is working without the chroot, and I don't want to add in any special casing for running it in a chroot. I could just call `os.chroot()`, but I don't want to have to run my entire program as root just for this bit of functionality (and I don't think there's a way to call `chroot` as a non-root user). I could also call `sudo chroot` as a subprocess and then communicate with it, but then I wouldn't be able to call normal functions in my python code; I'd have to make them communicate with the `chroot` subprocess.

As an example, here is some of the code I'm trying to run:

```
import os
import subprocess

def foo():
    subprocess.call(['pacman', '-Qe']) # Knowledge of pacman shouldn't be necessary

os.chroot('chroot/root')
foo()
```

This code requires root. I've looked into the `fakeroot` and `fakechroot` packages to accomplish this, but I still think I'd have to make a new subprocess and communicate with that, which would require me to change `foo` to handle that subprocess. Can I gain the functionality of `fakechroot` but with the feature of `os.chroot()` that the running python program is *in* the chroot instead of just communicating with it?

I'm using Arch Linux and Python 2.7.

Comment: In C you would `fork`, and the child would `chroot` then `exec` while the parent `wait`ed.

Comment: "I could just call `os.chroot()`, but I don't want to have to run my entire program as root". So just don't; you don't need to be root to create a chroot inside your home directory.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, sorry, I don't see how I can use that. Can you explain?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: You can do the exact same thing in Python.

Comment: @abarnert When I `chroot` I `chroot` as the root user on `chroot/root`, and file permissions on that directory are `root`.

Comment: @abarnert Do you have a solution for this?